# Receiving old pdf when i upload a new one on server

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, pdf, caching

I made a software that uploads a pdf to a different server that I am in (both servers are mine). The server2 receives the pdf that I send, does the calculations and return the result to the server1 (which I display on the browser). I also display this pdf on an iframe (which I send to server2), to compare the result with what it has on the body of that pdf.

When I upload a new pdf, and go to the screen where the answer is, the old pdf is still showing up. It takes some seconds or so to update to the new pdf. So, this is probably the chrome caching the old pdf.

I don't want this caching to happens.

I tried many ways to prevent this, without any success.

1) I tried to delete the old pdf from the server, then put the new one, and retrive this new one.

2) I tried to put some random numbers after the request (it is a ajax request to the 2º server), to force to get new resource.

3) Tried to put headers on send, on receive, inside ajax, on the php running on server1 to send to server2, tried to resolve on the python server side (2)....

NONE of them worked for me. I already look on the internet for solutions, none of them worked.

I really think it's something related with cache inside chrome. So, how can i delete the cache that the browser has, in order to see the correct pdf?

The url that i send is:
http://server/dir1/dir2/" + pdfName + "-.pdf

---

EDIT: when i pick the url from the pdf on the server2, that is inside the iframe, and then press control+f5 or control+shift+r, the pdf is update to the new one.

If i give control+f5 or control+shift+r on the screen where the iframe is, the old pdf continues there.

---

EDIT2: I saw the network tab in the console (chrome). I find out that the request is caching from disk cache. when i try to make the ajax request to the server, it shows the message "Provisional headers are shown".

Comment: so if you go immediatly after you upload in chrome and press `ctrl + shift + r` do you still see the old pdf?

Comment: No, i dont. If i press ctrl+ shift+r it updates to the new pdf. So, could be that chrome is not reloading the document went i click to see the result (the iframe with pdf + the result from the computation on server)?

Comment: I refresh the page with f5 and control+f5, but inside the iframe  didnt change to the new pdf.

Comment: so the `ctrl+shift+r` deletes the caches, so yes is a cahce problem

Comment: i dont have a clue how to solve this problem